# How to fill ContentPresenter by binding

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, contentpresenter

I've a problem to connect.

I started to connect my `tabs` with a `tabcontrol.ressources` and it worked to show the text of each tabs.
Then I wanted to had a scroll for my `TabItems` and it doesn't work, nothing shows in tab... I can't even use `tabcontrol.ressources` anymore...

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button Background="DarkGoldenrod" Height="Auto" Command="{Binding OpenFlyoutDataCommand}">
        <StackPanel>
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowRightBoldCircleOutline" Width="30" Height="30"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabEDCWaferData, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabEDCWaferData}">

        <!-- Used to create a scroolbar for tabitems -->

        <TabControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
                        <TabPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                  Margin="2,2,2,0" IsItemsHost="true"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="..."/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TabControl.Template>

        <!-- Contains the text in the tab item ! -->

        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="TabItem">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Content}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>

    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

This is connected to a collection of `TabItem`, where I've a function to add `Items` binding to an other button.

```
    private ObservableCollection<TabItem> _TabEDCWaferData;
    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabEDCWaferData
    {
        get { return _TabEDCWaferData; }
        set
        {
            _TabEDCWaferData = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TabEDCWaferData");
        }
    }

    public void AddTabItem(string name)
    {
        TabItem tab = new TabItem();
        tab.Header = name;
        tab.Content = "Temporary content";
        TabEDCWaferData.Add(tab);
    }
```

I read that I have to use the `ContentPresenter`, but I don't know how to bind it. I think this is not working with `TabItems`... 
I just want to bind it as I did in the `Ressources` by using the `ContentPresenter`.

I hope that I'm clear enough ! Thanks

**EDIT :** I try to display in the `ContentPresenter` the selected item tab content that I add in the function `AddTabItem.

Comment: Maybe a TemplateBinding  to the Content property of TabControl ?

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do with the `ContentPresenter`? Display the currently selected tab item?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! It was what I tried to explain, display the currently selected tab item content.

Comment: This is not an internal funtion of the TabControl control ? It's the control that decides which tab to display no ? The template is for all the tabs not for a particular one, or I don't understand and so excuse me by advance ;)

Comment: Hum, I'm a bit lost. I would like to display in this `ContentPresenter` the `Content` of the selected `Tab`. I hope that I'm clear. So, the template is for all, but the content has to change for each tab. Thanks anyway, I'm learning things (didn't know TemplateBinding) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ContentPresenter,` most times, this does the job:

```
 <ContentPresenter />
```

The default `ContentSource` is `"Content"`. That means it'll look at the `Content` property of the templated parent and it'll take whatever it finds there for its own content.

But that doesn't help you at all, and you don't *have* to use `ContentPresenter`; it's just a convenience. In this case, the content you want to present is `SelectedItem.Content`, which isn't a valid `ContentSource` for `ContentPresenter`. But you can do the same thing with a binding on a `ContentControl` instead:

```
<TabControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer 
                Grid.Row="0"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                >
                <TabPanel 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Margin="2,2,2,0" IsItemsHost="true"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <ContentControl
                Grid.Row="1"
                Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</TabControl.Template>
```

`TemplateBinding` isn't going to work with a `Path` such as "SelectedItem.Content"; it only accepts names of properties on the templated parent. I fixed your `Grid.Row` attributes, too.

Also, you may as well delete that `DataTemplate` for `TabItem` that you put in `TabControl.Resources`. That's not what `DataTemplate` is for; you use DataTemplates to define visual presentations for your viewmodel classes, but `TabItem` is a control. It already knows how to display itself, and in fact that `DataTemplate` is being ignored, so it's best not to leave it there; you'll only waste time later on making changes to it and trying to figure out why it's not having any effect. Your `TabItem`s will display correctly without it.

Comment: I found `ContentPresenter` on the net, but obviously, it was wrong. Thanks, this is the perfect solution ! How can I get rid of `DataTemplate` ? I've to admit, I'm a beginner about WPF. Can you show me an example please ?

Comment: @DesTunK Just delete the `DataTemplate` element from `TabControl.Resources`. Nothing's using it so it's not doing any harm, but having it there sows unneeded confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this part ! I deleted it because you replaced it by the `ContentControl`. I agree, and it's better to delete useless thing when you are a beginner like me, easier to not do mistakes ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this ?

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
```

**Edit**

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"  ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
```

Comment: The member `Content` is not recognized or not accessible and just `Binding` isn't working